# Как заменить один элемент на другие по нажатию кнопки? (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, dom

Практикуюсь в освоении DOM. На чистом JS написал как будет выглядеть мой ToDoList, но нужно доработать его добавив кнопку редактирования заметки, а также при нажатии на нее, чтоб появлялся input в котором мы перезапишем нашу заметку и чтоб появлялась кнопка сохранить, которая соответственно используя метод edit() сохранит в отредактированную заметку массив. Исходный код:

```js
class Todo {
    #items = [];

    get items() {
        return this.#items;
    }

    add(value) {
        const note = {
            id: this.#items.length + 1,
            value
        };

        this.#items.unshift(note);
    }

    edit(id, value) {
        const element = this.#items.find(item => item.id === id);
        element.value = value;
    }

    remove(id) {
        const index = this.#items.findIndex(item => item.id === id);

        if (index !== -1) {
            this.#items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}

class TodoElement {
    constructor(containerEl, todo) {
        this.form = this.#createForm();
        this.list = this.#createList()

        containerEl.prepend(this.list);
        containerEl.prepend(this.form);

        this.todo = todo;
    }

    #createForm() {
        const $form = document.createElement('form');
        const $input = document.createElement('input');
        const $submitButton = document.createElement('button');

        $input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        $input.setAttribute('name', 'text');
        
        $submitButton.innerText = 'Создать';

        $form.style.cssText = 'width: 350px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-content: flex-start;'
        $input.style.cssText = 'font-size: 20px; outline: none; margin-right: 20px;';
        $submitButton.style.cssText = 'padding: 10px;';

        $form.append($input);
        $form.append($submitButton);

        $form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            this.todo.add($input.value);
            this.#renderNotes();
        })

        return $form;
    }

    #createList() {
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.style.listStyle = 'none';
        ul.style.padding ='10px';
        return ul;
    }

    #renderNotes() {
        this.list.innerHTML = '';
        this.todo.items.forEach(note => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            const span = document.createElement('span');
            const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            const editButton = document.createElement('button');
            const id = note.id;
            

            span.textContent = note.value;
            deleteButton.textContent = 'Удалить';
            editButton.textContent = 'Редактировать';

            li.append(span);
            li.append(deleteButton);
            li.append(editButton);

            li.style.cssText = 'font-size: 24px; display: flex; margin-bottom: 10px;';
            span.style.cssText = 'margin-right: 20px';
            deleteButton.style.cssText = 'margin-right: 20px;';

            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.todo.remove(id);
                this.#renderNotes();
            })

            editButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                const input = document.createElement('input');
                const saveButton = document.createElement('button');

                // li.replaceWith(input);
                // todo.edit(id, input.value)

                this.#renderNotes();
            })

            this.list.prepend(li);
        });
    }
}

const list1 = new Todo();
const todo = new TodoElement(document.querySelector('body'), list1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S. Там где комментарий, туда нужно все писать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть прекрасное решение

> element.replaceWith()

```js
 
 document.onclick = () => {
    //найдем элемент, который будем менять
    const p = document.querySelector('.container p');
    //создадим объект textarea он и будет инпутом
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    //добавим инпуту текущее значение параграфа, чтобы  не редактировать с нуля
    textarea.value = p.innerText;
    //заменим параграф на textarea
    p.replaceWith( textarea );
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p> super duper </p>
</div>
```